# Change color of series onclick events across multiple highcharts

Tags: events, highcharts, click

I'm looking to change the column color and the line color for the same series across multiple charts based on the click of either the legend or the actual column/line.

On the individual charts I have color changing based on clicking/hovering and I can show hide based on the clicking of the first legend. I just can't seem to get the color to work. I'd like to convert the show hide functionality into color change.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jlm578/asdgqzgk/4/

This is the chunk of code I'd like to convert or replace:

```
events: {
    legendItemClick: function (event) {
        var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        var series = $('#veiOverallAllLine').highcharts().series[this.index];
        if (this.visible) series.hide();
        else series.show();
        return true;
        //return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I understood your question properly :)
Anyway, you can "convert" the event into color change by first preventing the default action to be executed (which is obviously hiding the chart).

This could be done easily using
`event.preventDefault()` within the event itself.

Than you can use a general function to handle the color change, which takes the series as parameter, find its 'sibling' and than changes the colors:

```
function updateColor(series){
    if(series == undefined) return;
    var color = series.color == '#ffffff' ? '#851E20' : '#ffffff';
    var sibling = $('#veiOverallAllLine').highcharts().series[series.index];
    series.update({color:color});
    sibling.update({color:color});
}
```

(More generalization could be done here but its up to you..)

Than, the whole `plotOptions` should look like that more or less:

```
            plotOptions: {

                series: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    states: {
                        select: {
                            color: '#851E20'
                        }
                    },
                    events: {
                        click: function(){
                            updateColor(this);
                        },

                        legendItemClick: function (event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            updateColor(this);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                }
            },
```

Here you can see an example: http://jsfiddle.net/a366e89c/2/
NOTE! in the example only the upper chart changes the color of both charts, you just need to copy the lines into the second chart...

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! I'm also looking to have another chart that shows data based on what was selected in these. Do you think the best way is to set up a function like you did with color and do if statements based on the index or is there a better way I'm not thinking of?

Comment: It really depands. Highcharts is very flexible, and the implementation is totally up to the developer. What kind of chart would the third one be? a column chart? line chart? what bevhiour do you expect? I mean, when clicking on a series what should exactly happy?   *btw, please "close" this question by marking it as "correct" if your first issue was resolved :)